Gitlab CI -> ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I get this error when i try to launch python script that use "dearpygui" lib on gitlab CI env
I'am trying to add this cmd "apt-get update && apt-get install libgl1" on CI Job "before script" step, but i thik that this cmd need human action
enter image description here

maybe adding -y would work but i don't know this environment

@kim please never add links to screenshots. Just copy-paste the output

If you install additional packages as a part of the job, then you should tell apt not to ask for confirmation:
apt-get update && apt-get -y install libgl1

The same is true for rpm-based images:
dnf -y install <package>

